# What is the antonym of Update?

Tags: antonyms, programming

As a developer, I am writing a commit message to rollback an update. In my message I want to describe what I am doing which is the opposite of an update. I am looking for something like the word *downgrade* for *upgrade*.

If you wonder what is the difference between update and upgrade, check this link. [What’s The Difference Between Update And Upgrade?](https://fossbytes.com/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-upgrade/).

The word *downdate* quite exist (at least on the Urban Dictionary) but it means a [bad update](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Downdate).

Comment: I am assuming that there was an update applied that took the installation from version a.b to version c.d. Are you looking for a word that describes the reversion from c.d to a.b or are you applying a new update which removes some or all of the features of c.d but does not leave the installation with the exact features of a.b? In the first case you are _reverting_ to a.b so the action is a _reversion_. In the second case you have a third version, e.f which is still an _update_ from c.d but one in which the features are _downgraded_.

Comment: I bumped an external dependence introducing an error of compatibility because of the old version of our main framework. When I commited, I bump our own version and I wrote `chore: update to v1.2.3` and now I want something like `chore: xxx to v1.2.1`. _Revert_ is a great answer. Can you rewrite your comment as an answer?

Comment: My first thought would be to use the term "rollback".  Can be used as either a noun or a verb (though for the verb one might prefer "roll back").

Comment: @HotLicks _rollback_ is mostly fine but a bit to generic. In context, it would fit as undo would do. I think it is a nice answer to my problem but not to my question :)

Comment: "Reset" is another option, though a bit more ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your response to my original comment I see that you are looking for a word that describes the move back from the later version c.d to the earlier version a.b.

This means you are **reverting** to a.b so the action is a **reversion**.

This is different from the case where you have a third version, e.f, which is an update from c.d which removes features introduced at c.d but has cosmetic differences from a.b This would still be an **update** from c.d but would be a **functional downgrade**.